# How to get the target of element in web browser control VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm still learning VB.NET and I'm trying to grab the URL of an element in a web page loaded inside a web browser control. I want this URL so that I can pass it to another form that downloads the said target file.

I disabled the default context menu in the web browser control and added a custom one just to check if I can get the URL of the object I right click on.

```
Private Sub DownloadThisToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DownloadThisToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim link As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim url As String = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.GetAttribute("href")
    MsgBox("Link Clicked: " & link.InnerText &
        vbCrLf & "Destination: " & url)
End Sub
```

It gets the name of the file but not the URL. Also, in the default context menu there's an item called "save target as" so you can right click on any thing,even an image and not only a hyperlink to a file and can download that file. I'd like to get the Target URL that way.but I want to pass the URL off as a text and not download it through the default mechanism.

Thanks!

Comment: The code I've typed above gets the URL if right clicked on an hyperlink but  not if right clicked on an image etc.

Comment: "but not if right clicked on an image" - that's because in an image the attribute containing the URL / file name is "src" not "href". Read the docs for the elements you want to target and find out what the properties are called.

Comment: I thought so. but is there a way to get the URL from any element irrespective of which attribute has the URL? I guess I can check src and href.but is there any automated way?

Comment: also, is there anyway to get the location of the file saved through "Save Target as" in the default context menu?

Comment: You are building the automated way right now...so you have to consider all the possible cases. Create a list of all attributes that are intended to contain URLs (based on the docs), then check the element type, and look up the appropriate attribute(s) for that element.

Comment: "is there anyway to get the location of the file saved through "Save Target as" No. That's dependent on the user's settings in their browser. You're not in a browser context here.